# How to use a file as stdin when exec a command

Tags: go

I have this very simple code:

```
cmd := exec.Command("cat")
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
stdin, _ := cmd.StdinPipe()
file, _ := os.Open("file")
io.Copy(stdin, file)
_ = cmd.Run()
```

It works. But the problem is that `cmd.Run()` never returns. It seems after writing the file to stdin, `cat` still waits for more content.

I'm trying to do what `cat <file` does, in which case `cat` would exit after reading the file.

I wonder how to achieve that in go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you you don't close the stdin. Add `stdin.Close()` after `io.Copy`. `cat` will then terminate.

Also, I know it's just an example but there is absolutely no error checking. I assume that's just for illustration purposes. :-)

Comment: haha, yeah, it's just for illustration purposes. Adding stdin.Close() works, thanks!